# Flakehell with .toml configuration and pre-commit hook

Tags: python, git, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I'm trying to run flakehell as pre-commit hook.

my .pre-commit-config.yaml:

```
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:             
    -   id: flakehell
        name: flakehell
        entry: flakehell lint project/
        language: python
        pass_filenames: true
        stages: [push, commit]
        verbose: true
```

pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.flakehell]
exclude = ["README.md"]
format = "colored"
show_source = true

[tool.flakehell.plugins]
flake8-bandit = ["+*", "-S322"]
flake8-bugbear = ["+*"]
flake8-builtins = ["+*"]
flake8-comprehensions = ["+*"]
flake8-darglint = ["+*"]
flake8-docstrings = ["+*"]
flake8-eradicate = ["+*"]
flake8-isort = ["+*"]
flake8-mutable = ["+*"]
flake8-pytest-style = ["+*"]
flake8-spellcheck = ["+*"]
mccabe = ["+*"]
pep8-naming = ["+*"]
pycodestyle = ["+*"]
pyflakes = ["+*"]
pylint = ["+*"]
```

Still have some problems. When I try to use git commit I see that flakehell started working. After a few seconds it fails and I got the error:

"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 10: invalid start byte"

Without "pre-commit" it works great (I mean when I just type "flakehell lint")

Is it even possible to configure flakehell as pre-commit?

If not - do you recommend any better/working solution for python projects?

Comment: Minor improvement: you can use `entry: flake8helld` which is a `flake8` wrapper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your configuration is incorrect, you haven't limited the files that are passed to your hook with either `files` or `types` so it is defaulting to all files in your repository.  presumably you have some binary file which is being passed to flakehell

I also notice that your configuration passes both a path and has `pass_filenames: true` (`pass_filenames: true` is the default so you shouldn't use that)

you either want to list paths in args (not recommended since you always lint more than what you're changing) **or** you want to filter the filenames properly

additionally, `verbose: true` is not intended for use outside of debugging as it adds warning noise to the output

additionally, you're not managing the installation of flakehell through pre-commit which will add additional burden to your contributors to try and set up whatever development environment locally, most of the point of pre-commit is that it manages installing your tools so your contributors don't have to jump through hoops to have the correct formatting / linting setup (eliminating a whole class of "it works on my machine" problems)

additionally, it looks like flakehell has direct support for pre-commit, so you don't need to use the `repo: local` escape hatch as you're doing

putting all of that together, you probably want something like this:

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/life4/flakehell
    rev: v.0.7.1
    hooks:
    -   id: flakehell
```

if you want to go with your local configuration you probably want something like:

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:             
    -   id: flakehell
        name: flakehell
        entry: flakehell lint
        types: [python]
        files: ^project/
        language: python
        additional_dependencies: [flakehell==0.7.1]
        stages: [push, commit]
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the creator of pre-commit